# How Can I add this codepen in Elementor

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor, codepen

UPDATE: I'm attempting to apply the ripple effect to a specific section, but all I'm seeing is the background color and the desired effect only works in the HTML code area.

does anyone know how to set it as a background effect, so that it will be applied to a specific section

this is the code that I'm inserting in HTML code in Elementor

```
    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ripple Effect</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section style="max-height: auto; width:720px; margin: auto;";background: rgb(0,22,36);
background: linear-gradient(43deg, rgba(0,22,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,84,121,1) 42%, rgba(1,128,93,1) 100%);
 >
        <div id="ripple" style="height: 400px;"
        ></div>
    </section>

    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.ripples@0.6.3/dist/jquery.ripples.min.js'></script>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#ripple').ripples({
            resolution: 512,
            dropRadius: 20,
            perturbance: 0.04,
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe add link from codepen too, so people could know all context if needed.

Comment: @necrifede the question/code changed after the edit. It is now a different question and library

Answer (score 0):

Inside of `addGuiSettings()` is an external library that build the little GUI. You probably don't want to use that in your page so remove that. There will also be an error in the devtools that shows you that.

If you want to use that you have to use the external librery from the codepen too.

And you have to put the `<canvas>` part before your script. Otherwise it will show you "canvas is null" in the error log

Comment: I've updated the code that I'm currently using, which worked but, it only works in the code area, and it doesn't affect the whole section and it's not in the background, do u know any way I can fix it?

Comment: you don't add a new <html> or <body> tag in your HTML Widget! That will generate broken HTML code at the end. Also I don't know what is in your script.js file. The script creates a 720px wide canvas. If you want to have it bigger just increase that. Check the example/docs in the repo of the new plugin. There it is in the background